# Dynamically adding navigation links to app.js application

Tags: javascript

I am creating a simple webpage using [app.js](http://code.kik.com/app/2/index.html). I want to make a LIST that contains buttons that link to other pages; I can do so very simply in my HTML as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li class="app-button green" data-target="page2">working!</li>
</ul>
```

This `<li>` loads "page2" as desired.

My issue is that I want to add these buttons dynamically. The following works well to help create the buttons and add them, but they do not cause the app to navigate to page2:

```
function createLiItem(data, list) {
    //create this: <li class="app-button" data-target="page2"></li>
    var entry = document.createElement('li');
    entry.setAttribute('class','app-button red');
    entry.setAttribute('data-target','page2');
    entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
    list.appendChild(entry);
}
```

I am inspecting the console and page, and they are being created correctly. The following is from my debugger:

```
<div class="app-section">
<div class="app-content app-scrollable app-scrollable" style="height: 200px; overflow: scroll;">
    <ul id="rList" class="app-list">
        <li class="app-button green" data-target="page2" data-clickable-class="active" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);">working!</li>
        <label>text</label>
        <li class="app-button red" data-target="page2">notWorking</li>
        <li class="app-button red" data-target="page2">notWorking</li>
        <li class="app-button red" data-target="page2">notWorking</li>
        <label>text</label>
        <li class="app-button red" data-target="page2">notWorking</li>
        <li class="app-button red" data-target="page2">notWorking</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried adding the *data-clickable-class="active"* attribute, but that did not work. I also tried reloading the list element. That did not work:(.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: the list displays correctly, the new LI objects look like buttons, but they do not move to page2 correctly.
Edit2: App.js is this: code.kik.com/app/2/index.html

Comment: **What do you mean by "app.js"?** Anyway, your problem is most likely that the functionality that works--the stuff you put in your HTML--is because it's there at window load or DOM ready, and that's when whatever lib you're using does the binding. Once that's done, if it's not using event delegation to the top level container, nothing added after will have the functionality. Whatever you're running to bind the initially loaded elements needs to run on the new ones.

Comment: What is `data-target` and who is looking at it? If it is some library which is running at page load time and adding event listeners, for example, then it won't know about the elements you added dynamically. You may need to re-invoke it or something.

Comment: App.js is this: http://code.kik.com/app/2/index.html

Comment: @JAAulde: is there anyway for me to refresh the element? .reload() for example?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to do what you want, but I don't know that project so I wouldn't know what to tell you. Hopefully someone who knows it will come along, or you could contact the project's author and link them to this question.

Answer (score 2):

I realized that it is possible to correctly create these buttons within the list as follows:

- remove the *data-target="page2"* attribute from the buttons.
- add a *onclick* attribute to all the buttons.
- point onclick() to a function similar to this one:

  ```
  function transferToPage2() {
      App.load('page2', {})
  }
  ```

This works for me, but I am sure there are better ways to solve the issue:).

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement that I found.

Set the `data-target` and  `data-target-args` attributes on dynamically-created buttons, give them some distinguishing class name, and implement it like so:

```
// manually add the navigation event
$(page).find(".YOUR_CLASS_NAME").on("click", function (){
  var args = JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-target-args")) ;
   App.load($(this).attr("data-target"), args );
});
```

You could call the attribute anything you like, of course but using `data-target-args` makes it clear, I think.

The class name is required because if you add the handler to statically created buttons that already have a `data-target`, the target page is loaded twice.